# How do I get the height of first two <tr> in a table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I need to display only the first two rows in a `table`, and on click on the div I need it to animate `slideDown` and show the full table. I could have just set `display` to `none` for all the table rows except the first two, but that will ruin the effect when I want to show them all...so instead I figured I should use `overflow:hidden`, and set a height on the div based on the height of the first two rows of the table.... Any ideas how to do this?

STRUCTURE:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery's [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('tr').eq(0).height();
$('tr').eq(1).height();
```

Where 0 represents the first `td` in the list

Comment: What if I have multiple tds per tr?

Comment: You will still get the height using the same code, doesn't matter how many td's you have inside. td's are children of tr and they are horizontal. So height will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="div-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Script will be:

```
alert($('#div-table table tr').eq(0).height());

alert($('#div-table table tr').eq(1).height());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr:nth-child(1)>td, tr:nth-child(2)>td').css('height':100);
```

Comment: you don't need to us nth-child here. What is height:100 for

Comment: err, yeah i misread his question i thought he wanted to set the height of the first two rows in the table.